# Why Inheritance output is unexpected

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class Parent
{
    private void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("Parent's method1()");
    }
    public void method2()
    {
        System.out.println("Parent's method2()");
        method1();
    }
}
class Child extends Parent
{
    public void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("Child's method1()");        
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Child p = new Child();
        p.method2();
    }
}
```

ans is

```
Parent's method2()
Parent's method1()
```

If i am creating object of Child class then why output is of parent class method??
even method1 is private in parent.
It shakes my all inheritence concept.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would call the child method if it overrode the parent method. But it doesn't, since the parent method is private, and thus can't be overridden.

When your intention is to override a method from a parent class or interface, you should always annotate the method with `@Override`. If you did, in this case, you would get an error from the compiler, since the child's method1 doesn't override any method.

When the parent class is compiled, the compiler looks for the method1 in the Parent class. It finds it, and sees that it's private. Since it's private, it knows that it's not overridable by any subclass, and thus statically binds the method call to the private method it has found.

If method1 was protected or public, the compiler would find the method, and know that the method could be overridden by a subclass. So it would not statically bind to the method. Instead, it would generate bytecode that would look for method1 in the concrete class, at runtime, and you would then get the behavior you expect.

Think about it: if a subclass could override a private method, the method wouldn't be private anymore.

Comment: @ankitagahoi I don't see the point of "but" in your statement :)

Comment: If this is child class object and child class having method1 then it is not case of overriding.  Child p = new Child();

Comment: Now i created Child in different package and made method1 default in Parent now still same output. but as per you it binds at compile time but default shouldn't bind at compile time it should be overriden. y same output?

Comment: default methods can't be overridden by classes in other packages, so you're still not overriding the parent method. Add the @Override annotation, and you'll get a compiler message.

Comment: but at compile time how compiler knows class is extending in different package?

Comment: In that case, at runtime, the JVM checks if the child class has a method that overrides the parent method, and it doesn't find any, so it calls the parent method. The child method has the same signature, but it doesn't override the parent class, since it's in a different package.

Comment: @JB The compiler is always the one to decide whether a method is an override or not. How else could it implement `@Override`? In this specific case, when compiling the subclass, all information needed to conclude this is available to the compiler. Example: `package test; public class Test { void a() {} }` `package test2; public class Test2 extends test.Test { @Override void a() {} }
` Error: `The method a() of type Test2 must override or implement a supertype method`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: yes, I agree with that. But the compiler still generates a virtual method invocation when compiling the parent class. And at runtime, the JVM still dynamically dispatches to the appropriate method1 implementation, which is the parent one, since the compiler has established that the child method didn't override it, since not in the same package.

Comment: Yes, maybe it's fine detail, but the runtime doesn't even take the subclass method into consideration. The virtual function table of the subclass indicates up front that it doesn't override the method.

Answer (score 2):

by default child class will be having access to parent method. you are calling p.method2()... which does not exist in Child class so it is executing from parent...

Though method1() is private is Parent.. it is getting called from the local method i.e. method2()... so method1() has got accessibility in method2()....

Answer (score 1):

Private members are not inherited by child classes. Therefore you are just defining a completely independent `public void method1` in the subclass. Naturally, it does not participate in dynamic dispatch.